# fp->_IO_write_base and fp->_IO_write_end in OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, clang, fopen

I need to compile a C file on my Mac, which was written assuming only Linux and GCC environments. The file contains a line like

```
if(fp->_IO_write_base == fp->_IO_write_end)
```

where `fp` if a pointer to `FILE`. Since OS X does not provide glibc, this code cannot be compiled with clang and I get the following errors.

```
error: no member named '_IO_write_base' in 'struct __sFILE'
   if ( fp->_IO_write_base == fp->_IO_write_end )
        ~   ^
error: no member named '_IO_write_end' in 'struct __sFILE'
   if ( fp->_IO_write_base == fp->_IO_write_end )
                              ~   ^
```

`FILE` (`typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;` in stdio.h) on a Linux machine is defined in `/usr/include/libio.h` and it is like

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;           /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

But in OS X, `FILE` is defined in `stdio.h` as follows. You can see that `_IO_write_base` and `_IO_write_end` are glibc specific, and they do not exist in OS X's C library.

```
typedef struct __sFILE {
        unsigned char *_p;      /* current position in (some) buffer */
        int     _r;             /* read space left for getc() */
        int     _w;             /* write space left for putc() */
        short   _flags;         /* flags, below; this FILE is free if 0 */
        short   _file;          /* fileno, if Unix descriptor, else -1 */
        struct  __sbuf _bf;     /* the buffer (at least 1 byte, if !NULL) */
        int     _lbfsize;       /* 0 or -_bf._size, for inline putc */

        /* operations */
        void    *_cookie;       /* cookie passed to io functions */
        int     (*_close)(void *);
        int     (*_read) (void *, char *, int);
        fpos_t  (*_seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
        int     (*_write)(void *, const char *, int);

        /* separate buffer for long sequences of ungetc() */
        struct  __sbuf _ub;     /* ungetc buffer */
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
        int     _ur;            /* saved _r when _r is counting ungetc data */

        /* tricks to meet minimum requirements even when malloc() fails */
        unsigned char _ubuf[3]; /* guarantee an ungetc() buffer */
        unsigned char _nbuf[1]; /* guarantee a getc() buffer */

        /* separate buffer for fgetln() when line crosses buffer boundary */
        struct  __sbuf _lb;     /* buffer for fgetln() */

        /* Unix stdio files get aligned to block boundaries on fseek() */
        int     _blksize;       /* stat.st_blksize (may be != _bf._size) */
        fpos_t  _offset;        /* current lseek offset (see WARNING) */
} FILE;
```

I would like to know how to make the code compile on both Linux and OS X.

Comment: **Never** dereference `FILE`. Note that `_X` (`X` uppercase letter) or `__` prefixed names are implementation defined as of the standard. This is an XY-problem. What do you actually want to accomplish shich you think cannot be done in a standard compliant way?

Answer (score 1):

That is bad code.  The internals of a `FILE *` are implementation-specific, so `FILE *` needs to be treated as opaque - you can't use anything in it.  Because on some platforms, it actually is opaque and you **can't** access the internals.

You have to figure out what the code is trying to do, *and rewrite it*.